# Python Not Found Error Occuring in VS Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

When I try to do `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `N` on VS Code (to run the code), it gives me the following error:

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\myName\OneDrive\Documents\folderName\d.py"
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have already added python to the environment variables and even modified python by adding it to PATH as several users stated, but I still get this error. Also restarted several times, and even redownloaded VS Code and Python. I don't know why this is happening, it was working perfectly until yesterday when my run button in the top right corner disappeared and since then even that isn't being seen even though I have the coderunner extension.
Also must note that when I type `python` into a command prompt i get the same error, but `py` works perfectly. Plus, my code will execute when I go to run and debug in vs code, but not when i do the shortcut. If you have a solution for the run button not showing up in the top right corner even for java, that would be great too!

Comment: it looks like python is not added to your path environment variables. do that and vs code will find it

Comment: show exactly what you added to your `PATH` and exactly where you python installation is located on your filesystem.

Comment: @user i added the path to the python.exe file to my PATH

Comment: you're supposed to add the _directory containing_ the exe to your `PATH`- not the path to the exe itself.

Comment: @user so would that be the same path that I was using but without the python.exe?

Comment: yes. and when I say "_show exactly what you added to your `PATH` and exactly where you python installation is located on your filesystem._", I mean full (absolute) paths. You still have not actually answered those questions. and you're supposed to [edit] clarifications into the question post instead of providing them in comments.

Comment: @user finally worked thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

> 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

The reason for this error is that the system cannot recognize the `python` command. You should add the path of the folder where the python interpreter is located to the system environment variable path.

In addition, if you use *Code Runner*, there are the following settings to control whether the triangle button in the upper right corner is displayed or not.

```json
    "code-runner.showRunIconInEditorTitleMenu": true,
```

As a suggestion, the best extension to run python scripts in VS code is **[Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)**, as an official extension, it provides more features, including intellisense, debugging code, etc.

[image]

It would be better to follow [this start document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial).